# Overwriting files while ignorning patterns

Tags: python, distutils, shutil

Is there a way to overwrite files and folders while being able to ignore certain file types at the same time?

Tried using `shutil.copytree` `ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('*.bat','*.csv')` but I have to first delete the directory using `shutil.rmtree` for it to work.

I then saw you could overwrite with `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(src, dst)` but `ignorepatterns` no longer works.